# android httppost mysql without double entry

Tags: android, mysql

i am using HttpPost to insert arraylist values to mysql through php but i got double entry in my mysql i have mention my code at bottom

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://");
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();

try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("a", a.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("b", b.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("c", c.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d", d.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("e", e.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("f", f));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("g", g));

    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Log.d("a", responseBody );
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be executing the `httppost` twice. Try removing the line

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

You are not using `response` as far as I can tell.